# How to QPainter inside QLabel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qpainter, qlabel

I can not understand how to make the QPainter() draw inside a QLabel, here is the code I told would have worked:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush

class Labella(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        lb = QLabel('text', parent)
        lb.setStyleSheet('QFrame {background-color:grey;}')
        lb.resize(200, 200)

        qp = QPainter(lb)
        qp.begin(lb);

        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(0,0,20,20);
        qp.end();


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):

        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#040404')
        qp.setPen(col)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 200, 60)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lb = Labella(self)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Colours')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can only find examples in C++ same as for the Qt documentation, please instruct me where I should have find the information if not here.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qpainter.html#details) suggests to use `QPainter` inside the `paintEvent`.

By using the constructor like below, inside the method `paintEvent`, no need to call `begin()` and `end()`

(Your class Labella just miss a parameter to initialize the parent)

The method `save()` and `restore()` can be convenient to store a standard config of a QPainter, allowing to draw something different before restoring the settings.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush

class Labella(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setStyleSheet('QFrame {background-color:grey;}')
        self.resize(200, 200)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(0,0,20,20)

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):    
        qp.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 100))
        qp.save() # save the QPainter config

        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 20, 20)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 255, 100))
        qp.drawRect(50, 15, 20, 20)

        qp.restore() # restore the QPainter config            
        qp.drawRect(100, 15, 20, 20)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lb = Labella(self)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Colours')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks, but is it not possible to make the setText() to work with this setup? it seems no text appears into the label when the Painter is on

Comment: @user3755529  You are right, sorry i didn't understand this part of your question first, i'm digging into this to explain this behavior. What's your main objective for that, to redraw the background of  label ?

Comment: I have an HTML table Subset in a QLabel (there will be many of those labels to layout in a QVBoxLayout). Under the Table I want to add a canvas where I will paint a bar indicating where we are at in a 52 week price range for the financial instrument that the QLabel identifies.